# How can I change the daily image on a homepage using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I need to change the image along with associated caption randomly every 24 hours on a coldfusion homepage. I have about 50 images and captions and I don't want to do this manually every day. Could you point me to any examples of javascript source code? Thanks.

I also want to be able to enlarge the pic using a lightbox. Can someone tell me how to modify the code to do that?

Comment: JS is only for the client-side, unless you store that in a cookie and check it everytime it would be better handled on the server side.

Comment: Assign numbers to each image and caption pair, have it generate random numbers, and then just grab the image and caption associated with that number.

Comment: Added a coldfusion tag. This is better solved in server side, unless there's a specific reason for it to be in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't do those things on the server-side. If you don't plan on adding images you could just send the current datetime (if you don't trust the client computer time) and leave the rest to javascript.

```
oImages = [
  {time: '2011-01-01', img: 'path/to/image.ext', caption: "image caption"},
  ... more images ...
];
```

On page load, you just create the image tag and pass the source based on the server time:

```
window.onload = function(){
  for(i in oImages){
   if(oImages[i].time == "coldfusion_time") oTodayImage = oImages[i];
  }
  oImg = document.creatElement("img");
  oImg.setAttribute("title", oTodayImage.caption);
  oImg.setAttribute("src", oTodayImage.img);
  document.body.appenChild(oImg);
};
```

You just need to output the server time instead of the "coldfusion_time" in the `if statement`, and either hardcode the javascript array objects or output what you need with coldfusion.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to get the pictures to rotate. Now I would like to be able to enlarge the picture when clicking/mouseover with a lightbox. Would you be able to tell me how to do this?

Comment: By lightbox I assume you mean one of the plugin scripts for the various JavaScript frameworks, If not, then correct me and point me in the right direction. Basically, the script should do what you intend by itself, what exactly is the problem you are encountering?

Comment: Yes I want to use a JS framework and would like to have a lightbox that expands to the size of the larger image when the smaller version is clicked, using the script that I have now. Basically the way it's now is that the image is created in javascript and associated with the div in the dom. I've never created a lightbox before, if you could help and point me in the right direction that would be great.

Comment: What plugin did you have in mind? A link will help me help you with the implementation. The way lightbox work is by attaching an event to the image tag, that when clicked, or mouseovered, take the source and creates the desired effect.

Comment: i'm thinking about using the Lightbox2 plugin http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/ do you think it would be hard for me to implement? can we talk on chat? i think it won't let us post anymore here after a certain amount of comments. i'll send you my code via chat

Answer (score 2):

I would do this as a server-side solution.

It would be easy enough to create an object (or a struct) with a timestamp in the Application scope. When you load the page, compare the timestamp with the current time.

If it's less than 24 hours (or whatever your limit is) just use the information in the application scoped object.

If it's more than 24 hours, run the process to choose an image and caption, load it into your object, and recent the timestamp to the current time.

Answer (score 1):

script can download different images depend on the day. for example in 123 day of year script download 123%50 --> 23.jpg image

```
document.getElementById("image_id").src = parseInt(currentTime.getTime()/(1000*60*60*24))%50+".jpg";
```

image will change each day, not randomly, but i think this solutoun is sufficient

Comment: yes, but if you check the date with js, it will check date set on users pc, which can be anything... :)

Comment: of cource better do it on server side, but i think this is no really important application.. i mean errors are not dangerous

Answer (score 1):

Give this a go (Requires Application Scope), put it inside the onRequestStart method of APPLICATION.cfc

```
<cfscript>
    if( NOT structKeyExists(APPLICATION, 'homePageImage') ) {
        APPLICATION.homePageImage = structNew();
    }
    if( 
        NOT structKeyExists( APPLICATION.homePageImage, 'imageDate' )  
        OR NOT structKeyExists( APPLICATION.homePageImage, 'imageSrc')
        OR NOT isDate( APPLICATION.homePageImage.imageDate )
        OR DateDiff( "h", NOW(), APPLICATION.homePageImage.imageDate ) GT 1
    ) {
        APPLICATION.homePageImage.imageSrc = APPLICATION.Utils.getRandomImage( "/images/captions" );
        APPLICATION.homePageImage.imageDate = NOW();
    }
</cfscript>
```

Next you need to define the function getRandomImage somewhere (something like Utils.cfc and then store it in Application.Utils for reusability)

```
<cffunction name="getRandomImage" returntype="string" access="public" output="false">
    <cfargument name="directory" required="true" hint="this is the directory to select a random image from" />
    <!--- Always define a local struct to keep your variable under control --->
    <cfset var LOCAL = structNew() /> 

    <cfif NOT directoryExists( expandPath( ARGUMENTS.directory ) )>
        <cfthrow message="Directory #arguments.directory# does not exist." />
    </cfif>

    <cfdirectory action="list" name="LOCAL.imageList" type="file" directory="#expandPath( ARGUMENTS.directory )#" />
    <!--- the ceiling part will stop you from getting 0 --->
    <cfset LOCAL.targetFile = Ceiling( randRange(0, LOCAL.imageList.recordCount) ) /> 

    <cfset LOCAL.targetFileName = ARGUMENTS.directory & "/" & LOCAL.imageList.name[ LOCAL.targetFile ] />

    <cfreturn LOCAL.targetFileName />
</cffunction>
```

And finally, on your page

```
<cfoutput>
    <img src="#APPLICATION.homePageImage.ImageSrc#" />
</cfoutput>
```